# How to compare two images in Java?

Tags: java, image

I have tried with below code but getting an exception as shown below -

```
public class TestCaseFile {
    public static void main(String [] args) throws IOException {
        String imgOriginal = "C:\\Users\\nn252j\\Desktop\\personal\\photos\\Output\\minionFloppedImage.jpg";
        String imgToCompareWithOriginal = "C:\\Users\\nn252j\\Desktop\\personal\\photos\\Output\\minionFloppedImage.jpg";
        String imgOutputDifferences = "new_screenshot_with_changes.jpg";

        ImageComparison imageComparison = new ImageComparison(10,10,0.05);

        if(imageComparison.fuzzyEqual(imgOriginal,imgToCompareWithOriginal,imgOutputDifferences))
            System.out.println("Images are fuzzy-equal.");
        else
            System.out.println("Images are not fuzzy-equal.");
    }
}
```

**Exception Details**

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: net/coobird/thumbnailator/Thumbnails
at org.frontendtest.components.ImageComparison.adaptImageSize(ImageComparison.java:105)
at org.frontendtest.components.ImageComparison.fuzzyEqual(ImageComparison.java:36)
at org.frontendtest.components.ImageComparison.fuzzyEqual(ImageComparison.java:23)
at TestCaseFile.main(TestCaseFile.java:12)
```

Comment: You need to give more information. 
Which library are you using to compare?
Mention the requirement for the comparison

Comment: Tell us how you have added the library for this project

Answer (score 1):

You may need the following dependency in Maven:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>net.coobird</groupId>
  <artifactId>thumbnailator</artifactId>
  <version>0.4.13</version>
</dependency>
```